# How to display a CTA on mobile

Tags: responsive-design, cta

With the CTA on my site instead of just saying 'See More' or 'Learn More' I've tried to be more specific as in it relates to the content.

For example I have this one CTA that says 'Plan your wining and dining' for a food section my only problem is mobile as the CTA parent div has a limit width.

[image: Image with CTA]

As you can see the CTA text does not fit inside the button - my only solution is to make the text fit inside the button but then the button would like fairly big and ugly to say the least. What is the best way to go about dealing with this? Do I have to come up with smaller text to go inside the CTA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately it will be personal preferences unless you test it during user tests.

What you can change? you'll have to find the right balance between:

- Reduce the font size
- Make the button multiline (max 2 for readability)
- Change your label to something more concise ('Plan dinner')

I think you have it all.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking multiple line button - thank you for your answer, I will try and find a balance between the 3 things you listed.

Comment: You also need a smaller line height on that button for readability.

Comment: Or use something other than a button.

Comment: @MariuszCiesla yea I've changed the line height to make it fit better :)

Comment: @KenMohnkern I think the button is needed personally but if you have a better idea than I'm all ears :)

Comment: Maybe a competitive audit would be useful. Visit a bunch of other sites, competitors and others, to see what they do. You can see what works and what doesn't, what you like and what you don't. I imagine you'll see CTAs as images, formatted text, text on images, etc.